# Prohibition of killing a child animal with its mother

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy

In the gemara in avodah zara it states that it is a sin to kill a child animal with its mother on the same day and in turn the seller is obligated to let a buyer know if someone else bought a child or a parent that day (only on a festival day).

1. Why is it a prohibition?
2. Is it a sin if I didnt know that someone else bought a family member? Because if so, shouldn't it be an obligation for the seller to tell us that someone else bought a family member or etc on the same day?

Answer (score 3):

[Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) in Guide for the Perplexed 3:48 writes:

> It is also prohibited to kill an animal with its young on the same day
>   (Lev. xxii. 28), in order that people should be restrained and
>   prevented from killing the two together in such a manner that the
>   young is slain in the sight of the mother; for the pain of the animals
>   under such circumstances is very great. There is no difference in this
>   case between the pain of man and the pain of other living beings,
>   since the love and tenderness of the mother for her young ones is not
>   produced by reasoning, but by imagination, and this faculty exists not
>   only in man but in most living beings. This law applies only to ox and
>   lamb, because of the domestic animals used as food these alone are
>   permitted to us, and in these cases the mother recognises her young.
>   ([Friedlander translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp184.htm))

The [Sefer Hachinuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch) in [Mitzvah # 294](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40631&st=&pgnum=392) mentions a similar reason, and also adds an additional idea that not killing the mother and child on the same day reminds us that there is Divine Providence on each animal species as a whole:

> משרשי המצוה שיתן האדם אל לבו כי השגחת השם ברוך הוא על כל מיני בעלי
>   חיים בכלל  ועם השגחתו עליהם יתקיימו לעולם כי השגחתו בדברים זהו קיומם
>   ועל כן לא יבטל מן המינין לגמרי כל ימי עולם ואע"פ שהשגחתו על מין האדם
>   בפרט וכמו שכתבתי למעלה בסדר אשה כי תזריע עשה ג' לא כן מיני שאר בעלי
>   חיים אלא דרך כלל במין ישים השם השגחתו ברוך הוא ועל כן נמנענו מלכלות
>   האילן וענפיו ביחד לרמז זה ועוד נוכל לומר בענין על צד הפשט כמו כן שהוא
>   לקבוע בנפשנו מדת החמלה ולהרחיק מדת האכזריות שהיא מדה רעה ולכן אע"פ
>   שהתיר לנו האל מיני בעלי חיים למחייתנו צונו לבל נהרוג אותו ואת בנו ביחד
>   ולקבוע בנפשנו מדת החמלה

[Radvaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ben_Solomon_ibn_Abi_Zimra) in [Metzudas Dovid Mitzvah # 203](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47579&st=&pgnum=267) echoes the idea about instilling compassion in mankind, and he throws in some kabbalistic stuff as well, most notably the idea that a human may have been reincarnated in this animal:

> טעם מצוה לפי הפשט לקבוע בנפשותינו מדת החמלה והרחמנות שהיא מדה טובה מאד
>   ולהרחיק ממנו מדת אכזריות כפי מה שכתבנו למעלה במצות השחיטה ועל דרך הסוד
>   כבר כתבתי למעלה דעת קצת חכמי קבלה שיש חזרה בבהמות ואם נשלם עונו הקב"ה
>   מזמינו ליד ישראל לשחיטה לקבל ענשו ברחמים ואז מתעלה במדרגה הראויה כפי
>   משפטו הצדק ולפי זה טעם המצוה הוא משום ואהבת לרעך כמוך ואין ראוי לדון
>   אב ובנו ביום א' ואם ישחטם ביום א' אין כאן דין ברחמים גם לדעת אחרים
>   כיון שבעלי חיים הראוים להקרבה נאצלו ממדת הרחמים והכח שלהם גם הוא מושך
>   משם אין ראוי לנהוג במדת הדין הקשה עמהם דנהי דהותרה לאכילה מכל מקום לא
>   הותרו לעשות בהם אכזריות המדה ולפיכך נוהג בחולין ובמוקדשין אינו נוהג
>   ואינו נוהג אלא בשחיטה לפי שאז באה לתקנו ולעלותו וסוד מצוה תלוי בסוד
>   מצות שלוח הקן שהוא לעורר הרחמים בעולם כאשר נבאר בסמוך בע"ה וכבר כתבתי
>   לך כי לפעמים תתגלגל נפש אדם בבהמה טהורה ואם טהרה ונשלם עונה יזמין אותה
>   הקב"ה לקרבן ועל כן תתעלה ויש שמזמין אותו לאכילת ישראל ותתעלה אבל לא
>   כעילוי הראשון ואם נתנבלה או נטרפה ע"י סמאל וכחותיה זה לראיה שלא נשלם
>   עונה ותתגלגל עוד בבהמה טמאה ואם גדול עונה תנתן לעבוד ולמשא כחמור וגמל
>   וכיוצא בהם ואם לא היה עונה כל כך יטרפוה חיות היער ויש מי שכתב שזה רמז
>   הכתוב וריוח תשימו בין עדר ובין עדר ר"ל בין עדר בהמה טמאה לטהורה ובין
>   כל גלגול וגלגול מחזירין אותו באדם אולי ישוב ואם לא ישוב בכל אלה
>   מורידין אותו לארץ כדאיתא ורוח הבהמה היורדת היא למטה לארץ ואח"כ עולה
>   במדרגת הגלגולים עד שעולה אפילו רשע שבישראל אין נשמתו נאבדת כי חשב
>   מחשבות לבלתי ידח ממנו נדח ומה שאמר הכתוב והאבדתי את הנפש ההיא שהיא
>   נאבדת מכלל ישראל ובאה בכלל הגוים ולכן תקנו שלא עשני גוי והכל במשפטו
>   הצדק ואנחנו אין בנו דעת לדעת דבר זה על בוריו

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a good answer for (1) beyond "it's perverse, just as cooking a calf in its mother's milk is perverse" but as regards question (2), in Avodah Zarah 5B, the Bavli Talmud is quite explicit that, at times at which it is assumed cattle is being purchased for immediate slaughter (before festivals) the seller does indeed have to inform the buyer that someone else has recently purchased the animal's parent / child for slaughter, and that it is indeed a sin to do so without being aware of such situation:

"
והתנן בארבעה פרקים בשנה המוכר בהמה לחבירו צריך להודיעו אמה מכרתי לשחוט בתה מכרתי לשחוט

But didn’t we learn in a mishna (Ḥullin 83a): On four occasions during the year one who sells an animal to another is required to inform him: I sold the mother of this animal today for the buyer to slaughter it, or: I sold the daughter of this animal today for the buyer to slaughter it. This notification is necessary so that this buyer will not slaughter the animal on the same day that its mother or its young is slaughtered, thereby violating the prohibition: “You shall not kill it and its young both in one day” (Leviticus 22:28). "

( https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.5b?lang=bi )

Comment: Sorry ill clarify my second question, why is it that the seller doesn't have to inform on a day where there isn't clear immediate slaughter?

Comment: @Voctave I don't have text-based answer for you but from experience in buying livestock in 3rd world markets probably not dissimilar from those held in Talmudic times, an animal's intended use is part of the haggling process; also by observing the way the animal is examined and its age/weight, the seller can usually make a fair assessment (i.e. a suckling goat is probably being slaughtered pretty soon, especially if it's Sunday morning; a large billy goat will probably be kept to clear weeds, etc.)of what the buyer intends to do with it.Before a festival it's more likely to be slaughteted ASAP

Comment: That is, slaughtered ASAP regardless of age/weight due to the need to celebrate the festival